# CSS not displayed with $_Get URL

Tags: php

I'm working on displaying a user's profile using $_Get['id'] from the URL.
At this moment I'm able to find the user in the database but the CSS is not being displayed.

Here's the css working:
http://classbrief.com/profile2.php

and here's the css not working:
http://classbrief.com/profile2.php/?id=1

I'm so lost, please help.

Thanks,

Monte

Comment: What kind of apache rewrite rules are you using?

Comment: Isn't the slash the problem? Doesn't `http://classbrief.com/profile2.php?id=1` do what you need?

Comment: It does, please upvote 19greg96

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you use relative urls to reference your resources (without a leading slash which tells the browser to search for that resource in the current directory).

You can fix the problem by not changing that "current directory" and staying in the home directory of the page.

In the case of your example, the format of the url suggests to the browser that you have a directory called `/profile2.php/` and the relative urls in your html tell the browser to look for `/profile2.php/style.css`.

However, if you want to make a page, with the same relative url references in a sub directory for example at `http://classbrief.com/sub/index.php` writing

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">`
```

won't work as long as you don't have a `http://classbrief.com/sub/style.css` file.

So.. in conclusion:

- to access a resource in the main / home directory
  (http://classbrief.com/) from any sub directory, use a leading slash (`/style.css`)
- to access a resource in the current directory (http://classbrief.com/something/) don't use a leading slash (`style.css`)
- to access a resource in an arbitrary directory (http://classbrief.com/something/arbitrary/) from any sub directory, use a leading slash and write the path to the directory (`/something/arbitrary/style.css`)

I hope this can be understood

Comment: This is true, but it's not an answer to the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, what is the question?

Comment: dude you freaking rock!

Comment: @MichaelMontalban - if you think this is a solution, good luck when you try and use a URL that points to a subdirectory.

Comment: Although the first part of this answer works in this case, fixing the path to the css files is the correct answer.  I would either remove the first fix, or swap their positions.  It does have some value, it's just not the right way to go.